# Google App Engine SDK is too large for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web, sdk

I'm trying to deploy an assignment to the Google App Engine using 1.8.0, but the Eclipse deployment tool is telling me that the jar is too large. Here's the console output:

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7254171904073358945.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
java.io.IOException: Jar C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7254171904073358945.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.0.jar is too large. Consider using --enable_jar_splitting.

Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy9108871985364269416.log
```

I haven't modified the jar at all. I know that this was an issue in 1.7.7, but was supposedly fixed in 1.7.7.1, which I can't seem to find now. Any ideas?

Edit: This may be a problem on Google's end (they made the jar too large): https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/QHf9KCD4LaE

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 1.8.

Comment: I have [reported this issue on the GAE bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9387). Please star.